# How to initialize instance for test, when constructor call private method and return exception

Tags: java, unit-testing, constructor, mockito, testng

In my case,
Student.java

```
public class Student{
    private String studentId;
    public Student(String name){
        super(name);
        setId();
        range();
    }
    private void range() throw Exception{
        final studentDetails = Loader.load(studentId);
    }

    private void setId(){
        final studentId = "123";
    }

    public void getAge(){};
}
```

Loader.load call read property file and throw file not exist exception.in this case Loader.load method is static.

When I write unit testing,

StudentTest.java

```
public class StudentTest{
    private Student student;
    private String name;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() throws Exception{
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        name = "Peter";
        student = new Student(name);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetAge(){
    }
}
```

In this scenario throw file not found exception in `setUp()`. I'm using TestNG, Java 8, Mockito.
How can I solve this problem. Is there a way to skip constructor call `range()` method in it initialising on test class? My project doesn't use PowerMockito.
please consider provided code is example of my real problem.

Comment: Can you share the `Loader.load` method?

Comment: You have quite some errors in your code. you'll need to address those first

Comment: It's impossible to answer your question if you don't show us the real code.  The code you've shown doesn't compile, but you've said you get FileNotFoundException when you run it.  So how about you show us the code that you actually run?

Comment: Here's a thought: remove the loader from constructor.

Comment: Can you share the code where the `Loader` loads the properties file? I assume it is that file that can't be found?

Comment: @GameDroids I need a way to skip constructor call range() method in it initialising on test class

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I need a way to skip constructor call range() method in it initialising on test class.This is a sample code with my problem.I'm unable to share my real code,because of company policies. :-(

Comment: Well your real problem is that you're using a static method. If you could make Loader.load non-static, then testing your class would be more manageable. It's a good idea to avoid static methods for functionality that you're likely to need to stub.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I can't change anything of Student of Loader classes.Only can change StudentTest class

Comment: So you're not allowed to fix the code if your testing uncovers a bug?

Comment: The fact that Loader has been written in a way that makes Student untestable is a bug.  You don't want to develop software with low testability, as it becomes "legacy" very quickly.  Fix the Loader class.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem My duty is write the unit tesing for Student class

Comment: What would happen if you told the person whose job is fixing the Loader class that the lack of testability constitutes a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a `Spy` in Mockito. With a `Spy` you could for a particular method add custom behavior.

However, AFAIK you will probably have to change `private` to atleast `protected` on the range method.

Comment: I try this method.Of course this can't do with private.But I can't change Access modifiers or any thing in Student.java class

Comment: A spy won't work here.  You can't create the spy until you've created the object that it's based on, and that means calling the constructor.  So you won't be able to spy on the call to the `range` method in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem here is the violation of the *single responsibility pattern* (SRP) in conjunction with the *mighty constructor* code smell and the *static access* to a dependency.

You *could* surrender to your bad design and solve your problem by using <strike>PowerMock</strike> to mock the *static access* to `Loader.load()` but the better way is to prepare the values for the member variables of `Student` **before** creating a `Student` object and passing that (valid) values directly as constructor parameters.

Comment: This is correct.  Poorly designed code always seems to come out difficult to test.

Answer (score 1):

```
 private Student student;
    private name;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() throws Exception{
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        name = "Peter";
        student = new Student(name);
    }
```

This part will never compile.

1. You declare the variable name without a type
2. You instantiate it as a String
3. You pass a String ("Peter") as parameter to a constructor that expects type Name

Comment: Thanks.I corrected it.This is a sample code with my problem.

Comment: @JayaniSumudini you corrected it partially. you are passing a String to a constructor that can only take a Name-type. You'll need to show your actual code, not "something that looks like it"

Comment: ohh.My mistake.I corrected it.I can't show actual code,Because of company policies

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem no, it doesn't. originally, there was no correct answer. showing why would be either incomplete or too long for a comment.

Comment: The non-existence of a correct answer is a good reason not to post an answer.  Instead, _either_ use comments to try and coach the OP to edit the question into one that _is_ answerable, _or_ vote to close it.  But posting non-answers in the answer field isn't really acceptable on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem if the question is "why doesn't this work", the statement "this won't even compile" is at the very least in the right direction, especially, since the title states this: "when constructor call private method and return exception". Passing a wrong parameter will indeed make the system throw an Exception.